# Вместо сайта открывается PHP-Код

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache

1. Стоит php7.4, Apache, Ubuntu Server
2. При попытке открыть сайт, открывается php-код

Прочитав варианты в интернете, писали сделать "a2enmod libapache2-mod-php" , на что получаю:

> "ERROR: Module libapache2-mod-php does not exist!"

Однако сам модуль успешно установлен командой

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php
```

Переустановить PHP и Apache пробовал.

Comment: а сам апач запущен?)) а настройки для сайта сделаны (sites-available, sites-enabled, hosts)? а где лежит сайт? в какой папке

Comment: сайты лежат в /var/www/html/.

все остальные сайты работают (которые на NodeJS).

Apache соответственно запущен и работает отлично

Comment: libapache2-mod-php от той же версии php?

Comment: Да, 7.4. но модуль никак не находит